# Django CustomUser created in Admin, User notification by email

Tags: python, django-forms

Hobby developer, new with Python and Django.

Working on project which will include creating new users with a CustomUser(AbstractUser) Model via the Admin backend. On [Save] I want to auto-send email to the new user email [To:] and share the Username and Password provided when the new user was created by admin.

I'm using Python3.7 Django 2.2 on MacOS. Development being done in virtual env [Conda]. Email server setup in the development env as Backend File type. I have done 'extensive' search on forums [incl this one] ... tried the example code I could find. I have been able to send [then receive in Backend File] email on Form save but do not know how one would include the form variables in the email.

**VIEWS.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail


def notification_mail_send(request):

    form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        # SET UP MAIL CONTENT AND SEND MAIL
        pass
```

**FORMS.py**

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'owner_fullname', 'email')

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta(UserChangeForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'owner_fullname', 'email')
```

Comment: Django allows you to assign signals to Model objects. These get executed when certain conditions happen on a model. Essentially you are tapping into events within django, to use them to execute certain actions. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/

Comment: @Rupin thank you. I now use a @receiver(post_save,sender=CustomUser) in the models.py of CustomUser, thus an email [the same one!] is sent and received by the user when user create or user change directives are saved to model. However, I get that on Login the user is also receiving the same email [!] I assume when user login that 'something' is saved to the model [?] ... I guess that the different 'create' and 'change' directives receivers should be subject to the custom forms, perhaps form_valid()? the objective is to get different email sent  user change and user create, none on user login.

Comment: When Login happens, the User model is updated. There is a field that updates the last logged in time for the user. you can look at the field and compare it to the current server time, then not trigger your email, if the difference is lower than a certain time gap.

Comment: @Rupin Got it! Solved by merely adding `if created: ` in the `post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):` function in models.py.

Comment: Please add the correct answer to this question, and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to my fellow developers for assistance. I did deep dive into Rupin's suggestion and applied successfully using 'signals' : http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals. Solved by merely adding 'if created': in the post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, **kwargs): function in models.py.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access to form data with `form.cleaned_data[field_name]`, where `field_name` would e.g. be `"username"`.

If you are using a Django template to build your email content, pass the form object as context and use e.g. `{{ form.cleaned_data.username }}`

Answer (score 0):

When using the django admin you don’t need to write your custom views and forms.

If you want to change the behavior of the admin you often need to overide the `ModelAdmin` class.

In your case I'd suggest to override [`save_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods)